# Reportlab: how to align text in pdf

Tags: python, pdf, alignment, space, reportlab

I'm trying to convert csv to pdf file but when i add text(address) in pdf it does not align in proper way. Below image shows pdf details where From address does not aligned. How to give space from left side please help me

Actual o/p in pdf

[image]

Expected o/p

```
                                        From:
                                        SAIFEE SHIP SPARE PARTS AND CHANDLERS
                                        TRN: 100069582300003
                                        AL JADAF
                                        UNITED ARAB EMIRATES
                                        Fax: 0097148124444
```

i tried below code

```
         style_right = ParagraphStyle(name='right', parent=styles[
'Normal'], alignment=TA_RIGHT)

       # PDF Text - Content
        line11 = 'From:'
        line12 = 'SAIFEE SHIP SPARE PARTS AND CHANDLERS'
        line13 = 'TRN: 100069582300003'
        line14 = 'AL JADAF'
        line15 = 'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES'
        line16 = 'Fax: 0097148124444'

        elements.append(Paragraph(line11, style_right))
        elements.append(Paragraph(line12, style_right))
        elements.append(Paragraph(line13, style_right))
        elements.append(Paragraph(line14, style_right))
        elements.append(Paragraph(line15, style_right))
        elements.append(Paragraph(line16, style_right))
        elements.append(Spacer(inch, .25 * inch))
```

Answer (score 1):

`alignment=TA_RIGHT` enforces every line to be at extreme right of the document.

change your paragraph style to:

```
    style_right = ParagraphStyle(name='right',leftIndent=250)
```

adjust the value of `leftIndent` according to the width of your document.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF image is correct as per code (right aligned). You can use left style and give x, y position (or something like that) for FROM address to start.(I did this kind of things in JasperReports, may be useful for you).